# How to use css namespacing to avoid css conflicts?

Tags: css, namespaces

**pnotify.css:**

```
.ui-pnotify-container {
background-position: 0 0;
padding: .8em;
left: 0;
width: 290px;
background-color: #fcf8e3;
margin: 0;
position: relative ;
color: #c09853;
}
```

was overridden by this part in

**app.css:**

```
.alert {
width: 366px;
padding: 13px 10px;
margin-left: -183px;
margin-top: -200px;
border: 1px solid #999;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
z-index: 1060;
background-color: #e2e7eb;
color: #666666;
text-align: center;
}
```

But as a temporary fix , i used the "!important" .As the project gets bigger, this will not be a good option. Will css namespacing help? I'm unclear as to how to do it.

Comment: can you share your html header tag here?

Comment: you mean this?
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="css/jquery.pnotify.default.css">
</head>

Comment: here which one you want to execute `.ui-pnotify-container` or this `.alert`

Comment: The pnotify container's style should not be overridden by the app's alert